# Programatic NSLayoutConstraints in a single string

Tags: objective-c, nslayoutconstraint

Is there a way to combine below 3 syntax lines into a single one statement like (which doesn't work):

```
[_cardsContainer addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[cardContainer1]|[cardContainer2]|[cardContainer3]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary]];

1. [_cardsContainer addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[cardContainer1]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary]];
2. [_cardsContainer addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[cardContainer2]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary]];
3. [_cardsContainer addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[cardContainer3]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary]];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but you can do it in two lines:

```
[_cardsContainer addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[cardContainer1]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary]];
```

This pins card container 1 to the top and bottom of the superview. Then:

```
[_cardsContainer addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[cardContainer1][cardContainer2][cardContainer3]|"  options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTop | NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBottom metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary]];
```

Which aligns the top and bottom of the remaining card containers.

This assumes you want the views laid out next to each other, you didn't actually specify any horizontal layout details.

It helps when using the visual format to think about each line of visual format language representing a single row or column of layout in your view.

Comment: All great answers and so fast! Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, no.

Comment: Bummer. I'll wait a day or so and see if by chance somebody throws something up, if not I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really a single line, but you can reduce the duplication of your three lines by doing them in a loop:

```
for (NSView *view in @[cardContainer1, cardContainer2, cardContainer3]) {
    [_cardsContainer addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[view]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(view)]];
}
```